# How can I write a generic TypeScript function that takes a mutable or immutable array as parameter

Tags: typescript, generics

I tried to write the following method.

It started getting very complicated, because now every method that receives the result from `catchUndefinedList` must be capable of handling mutable and immutable arrays.

Can anybody help me please?

```js
/**
 * Catch any errors with a list.
 */
export function catchUndefinedList<T> (list: readonly T[] | T[]): readonly T[] | T[] {
  return nullOrUndefined(list) || !list?.length ? [] : list
}
```

EDIT: added `nullOrUndefined`

```js
export function nullOrUndefined (el: any): el is (undefined | null) {
  return typeof el === 'undefined' || el === null
}
```

EDIT: added some easy example to showcase the problem.

As can be seen `catchUndefinedList` receives an `list1`, which is a mutable array, as parameter.
In this case it will then output an immutable array even though `list1` was mutable and the return of `catchUndefinedList` is simply the parameter `list` when `list` is not undefined.

When trying to push to `list2` it will fail due to immutability and return TS2339.

```js
const list1 = ['foo']
const list2 = catchUndefinedList(list1)
list2.push('bar')
```

Comment: The only issue I see with [your code example](https://tsplay.dev/N53BoW) is that `nullOrUndefined` is undefined (and saying "it takes any parameter" doesn't help my IDE, unfortunately, nor do I know what's coming out of it).  Note that `readonly T[]` is a supertype of `T[]` so `readonly T[] | T[]` is essentially just `readonly T[]`. That is, if your function will automatically accept mutable arrays if it accepts immutable ones.  It would help if you could provide a [mre] of your issue, which would clearly demonstrate the problem (by indicating how it's "getting very complicated").  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz thank you for your comment. I added nullOrUndefined to the question. Reproducible examples are a little bit difficult because the function is used throughout my code. I will look what I can do to add more information

Comment: @jcalz is right. Your posted code works without type errors for both mutable and immutable arrays. See: https://tsplay.dev/NDzY1W. So unless you can post code that shows how this approach is failing you, there isn't much we can do to help you.

Comment: @AlexWayne Thank you for your help. I added an example which showcases my problem

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/N9p3Mw) work for your use cases?  I've overloaded the function so that if you pass in a mutable array the output is a mutable array and there's no particular issue with tuples.  Note that you should really be using `--strictNullChecks` if you care about null checking, and then your input type should look like `T[] | undefined | null` or something of the sort.  Anyway if that works for you I can write up an answer; let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, this question only really makes sense if `null` or `undefined` are allowed in the type for `list`. So I am going to assume you meant to allow that.

---

It sounds like you want the return value of the function to be the same type of array as the input. That means your function needs be generic on the *array*, not just the member type of that array. This is because the `readonly`-ness of the array is the part of the array type, and not the members.

That might look something like this:

```
export function catchUndefinedList<
  T extends readonly unknown[]
> (list: T | null | undefined): T {
  return (
    nullOrUndefined(list) ||
    !list?.length
      ? [] // Type 'T | never[]' is not assignable to type 'T'.
      : list
  )
}

// mutable
const list1 = ['foo']
const list2 = catchUndefinedList(list1)
list2.push('bar')

// immutable
const immlist1: readonly string[] = ['foo']
const immlist2 = catchUndefinedList(immlist1)
immlist2.push('bar') // Property 'push' does not exist on type 'readonly string[]'.(2339)
```

Here you can see that the push on the mutable array is allowed, but the push on the immutable array is not. This is good.

---

However, this does present a problem with tuples. This is reason for that type error in my code snippet above. Imagine you called this function like so:

```
const tuple2 = catchUndefinedList<[string, number, boolean]>(undefined)
tuple2[0].split('') // no type error, instead there is a runtime error
```

This is a problem because your function returns `[]` in the `undefined` case, which is not a valid type for this tuple.

You *can* silence the error with a `[] as unknown as T` but that's not really recommended. If someone does try to do this with a tuple, you will probably get runtime errors in strange places.

I'm not sure how to constrain this properly, to be honest, since all tuples are subtypes of unbounded arrays.

[Payground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=28&ssc=71&pln=27&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVxUgGwIHkoBVFAE2AUxWEoApgCAuOAQxQE8BKdlnEwBnOI1TVa9SnAA+eQgV5wA3gCg4cKMBhIouGNzDAICOIIC8VuAHIJNOgxtz5l6-iJqAvmrWhIsIioGNi4aBwwaAAWFJKOlAAyIjAAPBpwACrmIDDAVKLaHJQ4BNxwqADWKBAA7igA2gC6agB8YgTJ7FnyHgRy5VQO0vyZqunauvpi6Zq9pLFDDIwdwjDKsrIzcACEKzAA-AB0BHkA5jBRW5r7cE2copXVdfeZV3Dse+m83r4A9L9wAC2SBgHAARic1GgcKs4HsAIxwCy3GwICAQGzNaEoWF7ABMSLg4UiMUGUgYSVWy2S8O++MOYCQwiijBsYI4UBs3zU-yEgOBoIhwChMPgmH5CPYhWKKFKcFWUDopzuyPqqPRmJFOLFEuSBORxOiC3JiWSjHFgIR3wt9MZzNZ7M5yl5hmM5igUGgfwBujAkOxsN9J31RIiRrJ8UpqXqCqVABoFICwcAoAmweiTlxGi1xBHhnBeezKGog8A8fUAAyNQ7CP2YGCsrkFgHVOCu4Duz2poTa4BFNtRFMdkScLSoLCAjsprtAA)

---

That said, this seems pretty complex for a simple null check. Are you sure this is the path you want to go down?

All this code does is:

- when `list` is null or undefined it returns a new array of zero items
- when `list` is an array of zero items, it returns a new array of zero items
- when `list` is an array of one or more items, it returns `list`.

Which seems to me would be practically identical to the [Nullish coalescing operator `??`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)

```
list ?? []
```

The only difference between your code and this line is that when there is zero items `list` is returned instead of a new empty array. But it's still an empty array, so that distinction *probably* doesn't matter.

But this behaves sensibly in all the above cases:

```
// mutable
const list1 = ['foo'] as string[] | undefined
const list2 = list1 ?? []
list2.push('bar')

// immutable
const immlist1 = ['foo'] as readonly string[] | undefined
const immlist2 = immlist1 ?? []
immlist2.push('bar') // type error

// tuple
const tuple1 = ['a', 1] as [string, number] | undefined
const tuple2 = tuple1 ?? []
tuple2.push('c') // type error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEFsFcBcEMCMA2BTAUAYwPYDsDO1REBLfARlAF5QBtAcgDNNNaBdUWXUfAJyOwHNqbAD6hI2ACbJ6fZBIw58hEtABMlZWVAB+bTRapi+VQDoADpFwALABS14sbrQCUqVCFBFwUOEjRY8Ai9wI2hyKjpGZjYOUG5kWAkcRABPLmheASFQUXEpGWw5BUDPb1D1KmDQ8l19VCqVUwtrOwcnZ1APaBSzZFBkbm5MbjcuyDMUYqVocZRwmlpYWgAaUFIYzmoePn5V7EhweAGRMUlpWXkA6dnkCtAZieQavSFUB5Qmy1tadBdOsG6vX6g2GQA)